# Android: background image not showing up on a device but showing up on every emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this weird issue. Samsung Note3 is not displaying background image of one of my activities:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fullscreen_bg"
        tools:context="com.myapp.views.activities.LoginActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

`fullscreen_bg` image is present in each `drawable` folder. Every emulator I've run my app on was displaying this image correctly but on this phone model it's not. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the resolution of your image?

I think is because the resolution of the image. Try to scale down the image to the half just to do a test.

Also if you are using different drawable-XXX, try to use only "drawable" without sufixes.